# Python: Create dictionary from string containing python dictionary / tuples

Tags: python

I have a following string in python. I need to convert this into a dictionary.

```
myStr='users="""[{"id": "Id0001", "name": "XYZ", "password": "p@$$wrd", "roles": "foo(admin)"}]""",tearDown=True,num=1000'
```

Derived dictionary should look like,

```
myDict['users']='"""[{"id": "Id0001", "name": "XYZ", "password": "p@$$wrd", "roles": "foo(admin)"}]"""'
myDict['tearDown']='True'
myDict['num']='1000'
```

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Why are you creating it as a string first? Why not just create the dictionary directly?

Comment: @depperm: probably not. what should he try? either there's a function that already does it, or it's very difficult to do it yourself.

Comment: @depperm: No I haven't tried. I am reading this line from a file

Comment: What is creating the file? Are you able to change it to write something more suitable for your end goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code solved the problem,

```
myDict = dict()
split_params = params.split('=')
split_param_len = len(split_params)
index = 0
m_key = m_val = None 
while index < split_param_len:
    inner_split = split_params[index].rsplit(",", 1)
    for tem_split in inner_split:
        if m_key is None:
            m_key = tem_split
        elif m_val is None:
            m_val = tem_split

        if m_key and m_val:
            myDict[m_key] = m_val
            m_key = m_val = None
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your string consists of valid Python assignment statements separated by commas instead of semicolons (which would've made the entire string valid Python), you can split the string by commas and keep concatenating the fragments until they are recognized by `ast.literal_eval` as valid Python expressions:

```
from ast import literal_eval
myStr='users="""[{"id": "Id0001", "name": "XYZ", "password": "p@$$wrd", "roles": "foo(admin)"}]""",tearDown=True,num=1000'
var = value = None
myDict = {}
for fragment in myStr.split(','):
    if not value:
        var, value = fragment.split('=', 1)
    else:
        value += ',' + fragment
    try:
        literal_eval(value)
        myDict[var] = value
        value = None
    except SyntaxError:
        pass
print(myDict)
```

This outputs:

```
{'users': '"""[{"id": "Id0001", "name": "XYZ", "password": "p@$$wrd", "roles": "foo(admin)"}]"""', 'tearDown': 'True', 'num': '1000'}
```

Comment: Good thinking, this should be robust enough to handle changes in the structure of the strings/dictionaries or their ordering.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Not sure the point of this, if the string was formatted better you could just do a `for` loop that is something like `(0, 6, 2)` and get everything but heres, this. I think after I get some coffee maybe we could do something with `re` and the groups.

```
import pprint

myStr = 'users="""[{"id": "Id0001", "name": "XYZ", "password": "p@$$wrd","roles": "foo(admin)"}]""",tearDown=True, num=1000'

myStr = myStr.split('=')
for i in range(1, 3):
    myStr[i] = myStr[i].split(',')

myStr[1][1] = ''.join(myStr[1][:-1])
myStr[2][-1] = myStr[2][-1].strip()

myDict = {}

myDict[myStr[0]] = myStr[1][1]
myDict[myStr[1][-1]] = myStr[2][0]
myDict[myStr[2][-1]] = myStr[3]


pprint.pprint(myDict)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 write.py 
> {'num': '1000',
>  'tearDown': 'True',
>  'users': '"""[{"id": "Id0001" "name": "XYZ" "password": "p@$$wrd""roles": '
>           '"foo(admin)"}]"""'}
> ```

Answer (score -1):

This code solves the task, but please never use it. I wrote it as an exercise for regex, but it's hardly practical for any real-world application.

```
import re

s='users="""[{"id": "Id0001", "name": "XYZ", "password": "p@$$wrd", "roles": "foo(admin)"}]""",tearDown=True,num=1000'
d = dict()

first_key = re.search('\w+',s).group(0)
first_value = re.search('(?<==)(.*)(?=,tear)',s).group(0)
d[first_key]=first_value

second_key = re.search('tearDown',s).group(0)
second_value = re.search('(?<=tearDown=)(.*)(?=,)',s).group(0)
d[second_key] = second_value

third_tuple = s.split(',')[-1]
third_key = third_tuple.split('=')[0]
third_value = third_tuple.split('=')[1]

d[third_key]=third_value

d
```

The output is:

```
{'num': '1000',
 'tearDown': 'True',
 'users': '"""[{"id": "Id0001", "name": "XYZ", "password": "p@$$wrd", "roles": "foo(admin)"}]"""'}
```

which is the dictionary you wanted.

If you want to add more keys and values to the dictionary, you have to find and implement appropriate regex's for each key,value pair. The third pair was a pain to do in *re* module, because tearDown could assume values 'True' and 'False', which not only have different characters, but also different lengths, so I resorted to splitting on commas.

What is the issue with what you are doing: I believe you are automatically parsing python code written by someone else, and are trying to recreate the same dictionaries that that person was using. If the data structure of each dictionary is sufficiently consistent, you might be able with enough patience to recreate it with a proper usage of regex. You will however never be able to predict when you will receive data in a format different from the one that your regex expressions can parse, and when you do, you will raise an error.
Also: dictionaries in python are unordered structures, and nothing will ever guarantee that the next dictionary will be called with its key/value pairs ordered in the same manner; in fact, they will most likely be called in different orders, even if the same keys are present in all dictionaries.

Solution: find where the dictionaries that you parse as a strings were originally output, and take the data from there. They were most likely saved in a database of some sort, so query the database instead.